# How can I use Python to increment 'tokenId' values in a .json file?

Tags: python, json, loops, increment

I have a .json file but I got the tokenId numbering wrong. I need to increase all values of "tokenId" by 1 number

```
[
    {
        "Background": "Red",
        "Body": "Tunn",
        "Hat": "Bambu",
        "Outfit": "Pirate",
        "Expression": "Sad",
        "Accessory": "Rifle",
        "tokenId": 0
    },
    {
        "Background": "Lilac",
        "Body": "Tunn",
        "Hat": "Bicorn",
        "Outfit": "Pirate",
        "Expression": "Angry",
        "Accessory": "Balloons",
        "tokenId": 1
    },

          ...
    
    {
        "Background": "Green",
        "Body": "Tunn",
        "Hat": "Bicorn",
        "Outfit": "Pirate",
        "Expression": "Sad",
        "Accessory": "Balloons",
        "tokenId": 3000
    },
```

is it possible to do this with python? i created this .json file with python.

I tried this code, but I get an error

```py
import json

with open('traits.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for item in data['tokenId']:
    item['tokenId'] = item['tokenId'].replace([int('+1')])

with open('new_data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Thank you!

Comment: `for item in data: item['tokenId'] += 1`

Answer (score 0):

The below seems to work

```
data = [
    {
        "Background": "Red",
        "Body": "Tunn",
        "Hat": "Bambu",
        "Outfit": "Pirate",
        "Expression": "Sad",
        "Accessory": "Rifle",
        "tokenId": 0
    },
    {
        "Background": "Lilac",
        "Body": "Tunn",
        "Hat": "Bicorn",
        "Outfit": "Pirate",
        "Expression": "Angry",
        "Accessory": "Balloons",
        "tokenId": 1
    },

    {
        "Background": "Green",
        "Body": "Tunn",
        "Hat": "Bicorn",
        "Outfit": "Pirate",
        "Expression": "Sad",
        "Accessory": "Balloons",
        "tokenId": 3000
    }
]

for entry in data:
    entry['tokenId'] = entry['tokenId'] + 1
    print(entry)
```

output

```
{'Background': 'Red', 'Body': 'Tunn', 'Hat': 'Bambu', 'Outfit': 'Pirate', 'Expression': 'Sad', 'Accessory': 'Rifle', 'tokenId': 1}
{'Background': 'Lilac', 'Body': 'Tunn', 'Hat': 'Bicorn', 'Outfit': 'Pirate', 'Expression': 'Angry', 'Accessory': 'Balloons', 'tokenId': 2}
{'Background': 'Green', 'Body': 'Tunn', 'Hat': 'Bicorn', 'Outfit': 'Pirate', 'Expression': 'Sad', 'Accessory': 'Balloons', 'tokenId': 3001}
```